# Zend Framework: File Getter Action returns a spurious newline

Tags: zend-framework, file, download, newline

I'm trying to make an action that returns a file from disk to the user (via little download dialog popup box.) I've got it working great, except somehow a newline is being inserted as the first character. This breaks jpeg and doc files, for example. If I remove the newline from the downloaded file, the files work.

I've also looked through the boostrap and initializer to make sure there's not any newlines hanging out there. No luck.

Here's what I'm working with:
-Zend Framework 1.7

my action:

```
    public function getFileAction(){
  $file_id = $this->_request->getParam('id');

  //check if the id given is good
  $filem = new UserFileModel();
  $filedata = $filem->getFileByID($file_id);
  $user_id = $filedata['user_id'];
  $file_id = $filedata['file_id'];

  $this->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender();
  Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();

  $str = file_get_contents('..\\userfiles\\'.$user_id.'\\'.$file_id);

  $this->_response->clearBody();
  $this->_response->clearHeaders();
  $this->_response
    ->setHeader('Content-Type', $filedata['file_mimetype']) 
    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filedata['file_name'] . '"')
    ->setHeader("Connection", "close")
    ->setHeader("Content-Length", strlen($str))
    ->setHeader("Content-transfer-encoding", "binary")
    ->setHeader("Cache-control", "private")
    ->setBody($str);
}
```

Do I have something echoing a null variable and giving me nothing but the newline in my other code? I'm going mad trying to get rid of this newline!

Thanks
~vb

Comment: add 4 spaces in front on your code to allow syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1):

Haha! Success.

turns out I was closing my controller like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';

class RequestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

//stuff

}
?>
 // These two spaces were ending up in the
 // Output!
```

The extra spaces were getting rendered into the output because they weren't in the  section of the controller.

Here's what worked:

```
class RequestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

//stuff

}// <--- no closing ?> tag or blank lines after this.
```

Good luck,

~kyle